# Headless UI Dropdown - Open menu above the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

Headless UI provides an example for a dropdown menu, where when you click the button, the dropdown opens below.

[image]

The code for this is here:

```
import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div className="w-56 text-right fixed top-16">
      <Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left">
        <div>
          <Menu.Button className="inline-flex justify-center w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75">
            Options
            <ChevronDownIcon
              className="w-5 h-5 ml-2 -mr-1 text-violet-200 hover:text-violet-100"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          </Menu.Button>
        </div>
        <Transition
          as={Fragment}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
          enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
          leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 w-56 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
            <div className="px-1 py-1 ">
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`${
                      active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                    } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                  >
                    {active ? (
                      <EditActiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <EditInactiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    )}
                    Edit
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`${
                      active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                    } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                  >
                    {active ? (
                      <DuplicateActiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <DuplicateInactiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    )}
                    Duplicate
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            </div>
            <div className="px-1 py-1">
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`${
                      active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                    } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                  >
                    {active ? (
                      <ArchiveActiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <ArchiveInactiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    )}
                    Archive
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`${
                      active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                    } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                  >
                    {active ? (
                      <MoveActiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <MoveInactiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    )}
                    Move
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            </div>
            <div className="px-1 py-1">
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`${
                      active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                    } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                  >
                    {active ? (
                      <DeleteActiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2 text-violet-400"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <DeleteInactiveIcon
                        className="w-5 h-5 mr-2 text-violet-400"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    )}
                    Delete
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            </div>
          </Menu.Items>
        </Transition>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}

function EditInactiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M4 13V16H7L16 7L13 4L4 13Z"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function EditActiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M4 13V16H7L16 7L13 4L4 13Z"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function DuplicateInactiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M4 4H12V12H4V4Z"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path
        d="M8 8H16V16H8V8Z"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function DuplicateActiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M4 4H12V12H4V4Z"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path
        d="M8 8H16V16H8V8Z"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function ArchiveInactiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect
        x="5"
        y="8"
        width="10"
        height="8"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <rect
        x="4"
        y="4"
        width="12"
        height="4"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path d="M8 12H12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}

function ArchiveActiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect
        x="5"
        y="8"
        width="10"
        height="8"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <rect
        x="4"
        y="4"
        width="12"
        height="4"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path d="M8 12H12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}

function MoveInactiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M10 4H16V10" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M16 4L8 12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M8 6H4V16H14V12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}

function MoveActiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M10 4H16V10" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M16 4L8 12" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M8 6H4V16H14V12" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}

function DeleteInactiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect
        x="5"
        y="6"
        width="10"
        height="10"
        fill="#EDE9FE"
        stroke="#A78BFA"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path d="M3 6H17" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M8 6V4H12V6" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}

function DeleteActiveIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect
        x="5"
        y="6"
        width="10"
        height="10"
        fill="#8B5CF6"
        stroke="#C4B5FD"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path d="M3 6H17" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
      <path d="M8 6V4H12V6" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

What I need to do is to have the dropdown menu open above the button instead of below. Something like below:

[image]

Can anyone please help me figure out the correct styling to achieve this? It uses TailwindCSS styles.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

export default function Example() {
    return (
       
            <div className="w-56 text-right fixed top-16">
                <Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <Menu.Button className="inline-flex justify-center w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75">
                            Options
                            <ChevronDownIcon
                                className="w-5 h-5 ml-2 -mr-1 text-violet-200 hover:text-violet-100"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                            />
                        </Menu.Button>
                    </div>
                    <Transition
                        as={Fragment}
                        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                        <Menu.Items className="-top-2 transform -translate-y-full absolute right-0 w-56 origin-top-right bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="px-1 py-1 ">
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                        <button
                                            className={`${active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                                                } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                                        >
                                            {active ? (
                                                <EditActiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <EditInactiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            Edit
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                </Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                        <button
                                            className={`${active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                                                } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                                        >
                                            {active ? (
                                                <DuplicateActiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <DuplicateInactiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            Duplicate
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </div>
                            <div className="px-1 py-1">
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                        <button
                                            className={`${active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                                                } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                                        >
                                            {active ? (
                                                <ArchiveActiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <ArchiveInactiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            Archive
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                </Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                        <button
                                            className={`${active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                                                } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                                        >
                                            {active ? (
                                                <MoveActiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <MoveInactiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            Move
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </div>
                            <div className="px-1 py-1">
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                        <button
                                            className={`${active ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                                                } group flex rounded-md items-center w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm`}
                                        >
                                            {active ? (
                                                <DeleteActiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2 text-violet-400"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <DeleteInactiveIcon
                                                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-2 text-violet-400"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </div>
                        </Menu.Items>
                    </Transition>
                </Menu>
            </div>
     

    )
}

function EditInactiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                d="M4 13V16H7L16 7L13 4L4 13Z"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

function EditActiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                d="M4 13V16H7L16 7L13 4L4 13Z"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

function DuplicateInactiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                d="M4 4H12V12H4V4Z"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path
                d="M8 8H16V16H8V8Z"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

function DuplicateActiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                d="M4 4H12V12H4V4Z"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path
                d="M8 8H16V16H8V8Z"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

function ArchiveInactiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <rect
                x="5"
                y="8"
                width="10"
                height="8"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <rect
                x="4"
                y="4"
                width="12"
                height="4"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path d="M8 12H12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}

function ArchiveActiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <rect
                x="5"
                y="8"
                width="10"
                height="8"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <rect
                x="4"
                y="4"
                width="12"
                height="4"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path d="M8 12H12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}

function MoveInactiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path d="M10 4H16V10" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M16 4L8 12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M8 6H4V16H14V12" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}

function MoveActiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path d="M10 4H16V10" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M16 4L8 12" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M8 6H4V16H14V12" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}

function DeleteInactiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <rect
                x="5"
                y="6"
                width="10"
                height="10"
                fill="#EDE9FE"
                stroke="#A78BFA"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path d="M3 6H17" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M8 6V4H12V6" stroke="#A78BFA" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}

function DeleteActiveIcon(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            {...props}
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <rect
                x="5"
                y="6"
                width="10"
                height="10"
                fill="#8B5CF6"
                stroke="#C4B5FD"
                strokeWidth="2"
            />
            <path d="M3 6H17" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
            <path d="M8 6V4H12V6" stroke="#C4B5FD" strokeWidth="2" />
        </svg>
    )
}
```

What I changed was `<Menu.Items className="-top-2 transform -translate-y-full absolute right-0 w-56 origin-top-right bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">`

please checkout if it works as you prefer.

Comment: `-translate-y-full` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: `-translate-y-full` is good, but you may need to add some additional pixels: `-translate-y-[calc(100%+50px)]`

Comment: You can just add `top-0` and then add margin. Don't need to do any translate y with calc. Its already absolute positioned on the button :)

Answer (score 15):

Just add "bottom-full" class to Menu.Items...

```
<Menu.Items className="bottom-full" >
  ...
</Menu.Items>
```